# PHP form charset

Tags: php, character-encoding

I've been through several similar questions on Stack overflow, none of them gave results.
In my simple form i want to allow people to post strings like `"Pagé Caiçara"`

Checking my html head i have the following meta: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

My form tag

```
<form id="contato-form" action="some_file.php" method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
```

And i also have an hidden input to force utf encoding:

```
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
```

But none of them seems to work,if try to submit "Pagé Caiçara" and them checking my $_POST gives me:

```
echo print_r($_POST);
```

output:

> > Array ( [nome] => PagÃ© CaiÃ§ara [empresa] => Company [email] => my@mail.com.br [site] => nenhum.com.br [telefone] => 12 55558349 [mensagem] => Ã¡guia de Ã¡gua [utf8] => âœ“ ) 1

So... what should i try next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just an **output issue**. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your questions depends in which sitiation you use that output:

1. Process in PHP and return a result / print html page

   > If you process given data and print result in html page with `<meta charset="utf-8">` the output will be displayed correctly.
2. Process in PHP and print as plain text

   > If you want to print simple output like `print_r()` add this line at the begining of you script: `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`
3. Process in PHP and write to database

   > If you've set your database/table character-set and collation to right values (utf-8) the result will inserted in the databese correctly (be sure that you execute these lines before you manipulate with DB

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db_link);`

`mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $db_link);`

`mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8", $db_link);`

Comment: How about if the purpose of the form is to send the data that the user inputed, via email?